# Spring Security header are not reflecting in API response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
package com.example.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .headers()
                .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.SAME_ORIGIN).and()

                .frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()

                .headers().defaultsDisabled()
                .contentTypeOptions().and()

                .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);
    }
}
```

I have added this class but still i am not getting any given above headers in API response.
I also tried by adding @EnableWebSecurity on class where all the APIs are mentioned.
Given Below is the image of headers in response. Please check.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb85U.png)

Comment: Thanks @harry. You are right. Nginx is dropping these custom headers from the upstream services. After adding this in ingress manifest. It start working. e.g. 
 
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
      more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
      more_set_headers "Referrer-Policy: same-origin";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 10m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reasons could be for the reported case are

- Spring security might be not coming in the picture. Make sure you're
  checking against accurate pattern (api protected by spring security)
- Web server is filtering the set headers. As you're using `Nginx` so you should check for any misconfigurations on the server.

Also,
`Strict-Transport-Security` is only added on HTTPS requests, so the following will be only relevant on https.

```
.httpStrictTransportSecurity()
.maxAgeInSeconds(31536000)
.includeSubDomains(true);
```

Comment: Thanks @harry. You are right. Nginx is dropping these custom headers from the upstream services. After adding this in ingress manifest. It start working. e.g. 
 
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
      more_set_headers "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
      more_set_headers "Referrer-Policy: same-origin";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 10m